# Physicality of electroweak bosons

Tags: standard-model, scattering, higgs, electroweak

The energies achieved at modern particle accelerators are much higher than the all scales relevant to the electroweak unification. I was therefore wondering why what is measured at scattering experiments above these energies are still the $W^{\pm}$, $Z$ and $\gamma$ and not the massless electroweak bosons $W^{1,2,3}$ and $B$.
I had a few ideas also by looking at other questions and answers:

- Could it be that the electroweak vector bosons are not eigenstates of the free Hamiltonian and are therefore not on-shell asymptotic states that are the observable products of scattering experiments?
- Or someone stated that the mass in cross sections becomes effectively irrelevant at certain scales, hence the cross section looks as if the vector bosons involved in the interaction were massless and mass to energy ratio gives small corrections to the scattering amplitude (though I don't see how that's the case since above unification energy the vectors of EW force should be truly massless).
- Or is it the case that the conditions that lead to the re-establishment of the electroweak symmetry cannot be achieved locally in an experiment but the whole universe should be at a higher vacuum energy? If that's the case what particles would a scattering experiment in the electroweak epoch conditions produce?

I'm sure this question has been asked a lot but I really couldn't find a clear solution to my doubts.

Comment: [Nice recent reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.09435).  All expected results of the SSBroken sector observed at LHC. The energy is not so high as to obscure the effective SSB vacuum through multiple interactions in the fireball.